# Замена ключа с изображениями для слайдера компонента catalog.element

Tags: php, битрикс, битрикс24

Имеется дефолтный компонент catalog.element использующий ключ MORE_PHOTO в котором должны быть изображения товара, которые потом будут использоваться в слайдере. Изображения товара выгружаются из каталога 1С и имеет поле MORE_PHOTO_SITE. Поле уже не может быть изменено так как слишком много товара и каталог используется на многих проектах. Мне нужно каким то образом изменить использующийся ключ в компоненте catalog.element с MORE_PHOTO на MORE_PHOTO_SITE. Как это сделать не могу понять. Пытался разобраться в дефолтном компоненте и не нашел ничего связанного с MORE_PHOTO.

Comment: Можно просто взять и подменить данные в result_modifier.php. Думаю, это самый простой способ.

Comment: Я так и сделал. Меня беспокоит скорость с которой он это делает. Думаю, что было бы правильней это исправить как то в самом файле компонента. Но я не могу понять где вообще там это все происходит. Где он создает массив с JS_OFFERS и дт.

Comment: Если мой вариант не подходит, то нужно разбираться с компонентом. Искать где все это определяется. Но нужно учитывать много нюансов. Во-первых, компонент модифицировать нельзя, если нужно вносить изменения - только кастомизировать. Во-вторых, нужно учитывать что где-то на других страницах сайта (или на другом сайте этой же установки, возможно в будущем) может использоваться этот же компонент, но с MORE_PHOTO.